# Problem with NgStyle after upgrading angular from 5.1 to 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

[image]After upgrading Angular form 5.1 to 8, the module NgStyle which is imported from '@angular/common' giving error,
 in 5.1 NgStyle use to accept 3 argumentand  and in 8 it's accepting only one parameter.

```js
import { NgStyle } from "@angular/common";

@Directive({
 selector: '[chartContainer]'
})
export class ChartContainerDirective implements OnInit {
this.ngStyle = new NgStyle(this._differs, divRef, this.renderer);
}
```

please suggest a way out for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular version 8 has change API for NgStyle so it now only accept 1 argument

This is is constructor of NgStyle

```
new NgStyle(delegate: ɵNgStyleImpl): NgStyle
```

So you need to pass in a delegate

Comment: can u please explain what is delegate of type eNgstyleImpl , not getting much about that  and what should be assigned for delegate ,if want to create a new instance of NgStyle